# Working with the different devices in trigger iO

Tags: iphone, html, trigger.io

I am creating application using triggerIO framework . I want to change my html page according to the screen resolution for the iPhone and iPad. Right now I have loaded two different css conditionally .But I like to know is it cleaner approach ? **OR** is there any better and efficient way to do this ? **OR** is there any in built framework available for this in trigger IO ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, we'd recommend creating interfaces which adapt to the current screen, rather than switching between different CSS files based on device detection.

That's even more relevant if you want to support Android, where there's a huge number of different screen sizes and shapes.

You could take a look at [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) for a responsive design framework, or [320 and up](http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/320andup/), which tends to be a bit lighter.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your app design, but I recommend using relative units like ems in CSS and setting font-size on body element.

In our app, we do something like `$('body').css('font-size', (window.innerWidth * 16 / 320) + 'px')`. 16 is default font-size and 320 is the width in px our app was designed at initialy.

So, for example, if some element is meant to be 100px wide, I set width: 6.25em.